# How many accounts of Hanuman's birth are there in the Itihasa and Purana literature?

Tags: hanuman, valmiki, vayu

We have the story of Vayu impregnating Anjana Devi in the Valmiki Ramayana, which leads to the birth of Hanuman. We also have an account of Shiva, through Vayu, 'creating' Hanuman in the Narada Purana.  Goswami Tulasidas in his famous Hanuman Chalisa calls Hanuman 'shankara sUnu' (Shiva's offspring).  If there are more accounts of Hanuman in various puranas, they may be brought to light.

Comment: It's not possible to count each and every account from vast liteature of puranas , Itihasa and to present exact number , nor it is essential to know , cause there will be many. It's better to change the title asking for some other accounts from the scripture than you mentioned.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because It is too broad to answer as is currently framed.

Comment: Actually the question 'How many accounts...' does not at all ask for the number of accounts but the accounts themselves, wherever they are found by people who read them.

Comment: Question seems to be simple but answer will be elaborative. Referring itihasa /purana  can give answer which was given above. I am voting to close as accounts not maintained by puranas.